# Use a function in a query. Php / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

Can you use a php function that returns a value in a mysql query ?.
for example:

```
function distanza($x,$x2){
        return 1;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE".distanza(2,2)."<'$raggio' ",$con);
```

Comment: you don't use it inside a query, you use the result of that function in a query. But in your example you forgot a space after `WHERE`, if you were wondering...

Comment: The `mysql_` extension is **deprecated** an will be **removed** in the next php versions. You should use [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or work with [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)'s. See [Deprecated features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) in PHP 5.5x

Comment: but I need to pass the values in each row of the table .. how can I?
such as:

$ result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE" .distanza (x, y). '<' $ within '", $ con)

where (x, y) are two fields of my table.

Comment: Your query is also missing the field name that's queried by the `WHERE`clause. It's hard to try to understand what you're trying to do.